# Caption below lstinputlisting in multicols + redefining lstlisting caption format

Tags: floats, listings, captions, multicol

I have 2 problems with `caption` for `lstlisting`.

1. I can't get the `caption` of `lstlisting` to go below the list when it's in a `multicols` environment. Although I've added `\captionsetup[lstlisting]{position=bottom}` to the document preamble, nothing changes.
2. Furthermore, in my documents I generally use a modified `caption` style which is defined as follows:
   `\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1#2#3\hrulefill}`
   To give me a horizontal line underneath the caption. I would like to add this `hrulefill` to the `caption` of `lstlisting` to make all captions uniform in my documents.

I'd be very grateful for all help I can get!

The minimal working example is below, together with a pdf of the output. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[utf8,12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{position=bottom}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{6}[\captionof{lstlisting}{The first 100 lemmata}]
\begin{lstlisting}
a
aback
abacus
abandon
abase
abashed
abate
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be a problem to put `\captionof{lstlisting}{The first 100 lemmata}` below `multicols`? For the second question: Have you tried `\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=myformat}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comment:

1. Put `\captionof{lstlisting}{The first 100 lemmata}`below the `multicol` environment.
2. Add your own format to `lstlisting` with `\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=myformat}`

Your example modified accordingly:

```
documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1#2#3\hrulefill}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{position=bottom,format=myformat}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{6}
\begin{lstlisting}
a
aback
abacus
abandon
abase
abashed
abate
\end{lstlisting}
\end{multicols}
\captionof{lstlisting}{The first 100 lemmata}

\end{document}
```

[image]